# not showing scheduled notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I was trying to make full screen notification app like alarm. the below code shows simple notification but not scheduled notifications. It does not showing any errors, but not working. Already added permissions in androidmanifest.xml

what to do?

```
  class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
  }

  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      var androidInitialize = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
      var IOSinitialize = IOSInitializationSettings();

      var initializationsSettings =
          InitializationSettings(androidInitialize, IOSinitialize);

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: notificationSelected,
      );
    }

    Future notificationSelected(String payload) async {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('notification clicked $payload'),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    _showNotification() async {
      var androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "Channel ID2",
        "Desi programmer",
        "ha ha",
        importance: Importance.Max,
      );

      var iosDetails = const IOSNotificationDetails();
      var generalNotificationDetails =
          NotificationDetails(androidDetails, iosDetails);

      print('above schedule');
      var scheduledTime = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: 3,
        ),
      );

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        1, "Task",
        "scheduled notifications", scheduledTime, generalNotificationDetails,
        //androidAllowWhileIdle: true
      );

      // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      //     0, 'task', 'you created a task', generalNotificationDetails,
      //     payload: "task");
    }
```

How to find out the problem?
Is there any working examples, that also helpful.

Comment: From where you are calling `_showNotification` ?

Comment: in button onpressed method.